# Was ‘The Return of the Archons’ the first example of “regularly scheduled chaos”?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, history-of, science-fiction-genre, society

In the original series Star Trek, the episode [*"The Return of the Archons"*](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0708476/) (*TOS*, S01 E21) has a placid, peaceful society with a scheduled time of utter lawless chaos. Several SFF works since then (like the [*Purge*](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2184339/)  movies) have had similar setups. Was this *TOS* episode the first use of this idea?

Comment: Interestingly, this episode is the first ever to mention the Prime Directive.

Comment: Hate Hour in _Nineteen Eighty-Four_?

Comment: The Morlocks' fake air raids to collect Eloi for processing in _The Time Machine_? Also Melnibone had an event in which its princes (including Elric) paritcipated. Plus a real-world example, the Spartans' staged wars against the Helots. (sorry, my 5 minutes ran out)

Comment: @Spencer: "Hate hour" is close, but doesn't quite fit the idea of a scheduled period of lawlessness and chaos.

Comment: [Rumspringa?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumspringa)

Comment: fwiw - there is nothing of note re: the origin of red hour in the generally comprehensive episode history "These are the Voyages: TOS Season One" by Marc Cushman

Comment: gah....don't make me go to TV Tropes....

Comment: @NKCampbell I already spent hours there and could't find a trope that refers specifically to "regularly scheduled chaos." The closest I could find were [A Fete Worse Than Death](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AFeteWorseThanDeath) and [In-Universe Catharsis](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InUniverseCatharsis).

Comment: "Hate Hour"? I think you mean the "Two Minutes Hate" which certainly is similar. For a regularly scheduled chaos *with a purpose* there's "It Could Be You" by an Australian author that I forget, about a game show with very unpleasant consequences ( Unlike it's real-life version )

Answer (score 1):

It's not the first, though what follows is, admittedly, an oblique or roundabout answer.  Worth mentioning: I consider "Return of the Archons" brilliantly subversive, while not necessarily agreeing with the implications. EDIT: this answer is meant to interpret the episode as shown, with the statements of filmmakers being of interest, but secondary.

The episode's Red Hour refers back to real customs.  The closest, from what I've read, is [Saturnalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturnalia#Human_offerings):

> In sources of the third century AD and later, Saturn is recorded as
>   receiving dead gladiators as offerings (munera) during or near the
>   Saturnalia.[35] These gladiator events, ten days in all throughout
>   December ... [were later] criticized by Christian apologists as a form of human sacrifice.[37][38] Although there is no evidence of this practice
>   during the Republic, the offering of gladiators led to later theories
>   that the primeval Saturn had demanded human victims.

Another Roman event, Bacchanalia, is even closer to Red Hour, but Livy's report is contested, and thought to be propaganda.  Such rites moderated to the Lord of Misrule, Halloween ("Mischief Night"), and Mardi Gras.  This gets into a sensitive area, but it's worth expanding on the connections.

Gene Roddenberry devised the story for "Return of the Archons."  He famously rejected organized religion, but was curious and quirky, not necessarily feeling the *same* about all religions. Finally, his parents were from Texas (he was born there), where "Catholic" meant neighboring Louisiana (and Mexico, of course).  Regardless of his stated deflections (IIRC), Red Hour is an extreme Mardi Gras, with leader "Landru" a common name of the region (spelled Landrieu).  So is "Tallulah," the likely source for "Tula," the female character.

The episode's cultists wear monk's robes, and obedience equals being "of the body."  The latter phrase is Christian generally, but perhaps evocative of consuming "the body of Christ."  Roddenberry's memorable reaction to communion (age "around 14"), as told to *The Humanist*, March/April 1991: "how did Jesus become something to be *eaten*?"

Thus, if the episode satirizes or slams Mardi Gras as religious rite, Roddenberry and company were following Livy (and others, presumably).

(In terms of actual fiction, the closest I recall is Asimov's "Nightmare," where  the regular chaos is very much unscheduled.)

Comment: A couple of things: Roddenberry didn't come up w/ the "of the body" idea - that was freelance writer Boris Sobleman. The overall theme was rooted in loss of individuality due to technology (ie - computers - remember, this is the mid 60s), not religion. There is no indication in any of the memos that red hour was meant to be anything other than disorderly chaos / release necessitated by the rigid controls imposed by the technology (source: 'These Are the Voyages: Season 1' - Marc Cushman)

Comment: Stan Robertson, NBC executive, summed the theme as follows: "the dangers inherint in a culture when it becomes too computerized and its most basic need, emotions, and functions can be programmed"

Comment: I've never read that book, but nothing above would have affected my answer.  Artists are not always the best at interpreting their own work, or necessarily conscious of their motivations, nor do they always tell the truth, especially when doing so could have gotten the story or script killed.  I'm aware of the era's anxieties regarding technology, but that's like saying "The Ultimate Computer" has nothing to do with race/ethnicity, because that threat also involves a computer.  Frankly, if you don't see religion as an obvious theme in "Archons," I'm at a loss.

Comment: That's fine - I'm just reporting what the actual production memos from the creators state

Comment: Perhaps a clarifying note should've been included; I've made this edit.

Comment: interpretations are generally opinion based though and not based on fact. One could just as easily (and possibly more logically) interpret the episode, given the time period, to be a polemic against communism rather than religion

Comment: Really, I was trying to be diplomatic.  By your logic, yes, it's back to the citation from a recent, respected source.  I believe this method CAN be sorely lacking, and is rather patriarchal (to put it mildly), in sending us back to authority figures for permission to think.  That said, I stand by the assertion: Livy's account of Saturnalia is a prior, published work describing regularly scheduled chaos.  At this point, I suggest we agree to disagree, and see if others care to comment, or vote.

Comment: the above should read "Livy's account of Bacchanalia."

Comment: I only see a link to a wiki article, which is generally not considered a useful source for the purposes of this site