# Earliest example of a wizard protagonist named Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, history-of, fantasy-genre, the-dresden-files

A [person known to me only as Unscrewed once noticed](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-92838.html) that the following description:

> A young wizard named Harry finds himself an orphan because of the machinations of a would-be evil overlord. His adoptive parents are cruel and neglectful. However, he learns his most important lessons (those of the heart) from a old, kind, and powerful wizard. He fights a variety of magical opponents, has a definite disrespect for authority, and suffers scorn from his peers. He eventually defeats the evil overlord, but finds the kind old wizard he respected so much wasn't as perfect as he originally seemed.

perfectly describes both *Harry Potter* books (which are extremely profitable) and *The Dresden Files* books (which have a cult following).

*Clearly*, this can't be a coincidence. Stories centered around orphaned wizards named Harry must innately call to something deep in the current zeitgeist, and there's bound to be a public some public domain work along these lines that I can exploit to become filthy rich and/or popular.

So, on a **completely** unrelated note, a question: what is the earliest story that features a magic-using named Harry? Bonus points if he's also an orphan.

Comment: Ah, a downvote. Is it too specific? I have seen questions in this tag as broad as man-made intelligence turning against humanity or as specific as hibernation into the postapocalyptic future, or even ["regularly scheduled chaos"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/140154/). So, what's wrong with mine?

Comment: "Clearly, this can't be a coincidence".... or, it's a coincidence.

Comment: @KutuluMike I see tongue-in-cheek, self-deprecating humour still fails to reach people across the Internet. (Aren't we allowed a little humour in our questions?)

Comment: Seems like youve found 2 of the only major examples. I'm sure there may be fantasy novels starring a Harry, but i cant find any link to a Campbellian-esque cultural pattern. That also doesn't perfectly describe The Dresden Files, IMHO.

Comment: @Dragomok sure you are. But when your humor is a joke made so many times that *you* already found it by accident on the internet, you can also expect fans of the works to downvote you and move it.

Comment: @Dpeif. I'm curious what you think is off in this case?  I can't find anything that's a miss against currently published Dresden books.

Comment: @Paul i dont mean its inaccurate, just a bit basic. IMHO that describes HP very well, but its not how i would describe HD, even though those are all basic plot points for both.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Houdini

Comment: @KutuluMike That's a good point. I apologise if I came across rude.

Comment: @Paul I think it's a real stretch to claim that Dresden suffers scorn from his peers -- he's incredibly well respected among the White Council *and* the Winter Fae, at the very least. He was made a Warden, he's the Winter Knight, and people go way out of their way to help him. Plus, he's never actually vanquished "the" evil overlord yet (since the series hasn't ended yet), he's merely vanquished "several" lesser evil overlords.

Comment: @KutuluMike depends on perspective, I suppose.  I'd agree with Dpeif who says it's perhaps too broad, but I would say that the 'scorn of peers' bit depends a bit on who you class as peers in both cases.  The other wardens mostly disliked him when actively serving. The Winter Fae now fear him (some) but many still don't & try and test his limits, etc.  The "Evil overlord" referred to in the OP is perhaps unknown; I took it to mean Justin, who he did destroy.  Channeling Obi-Wan, many of the truths we cling to depend a great deal on our point of view. ;)

Comment: It's explicitly stated in the books that [Harry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Houdini) [Blackstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Blackstone,_Sr.) [Copperfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Copperfield_(illusionist)) Dresden is named after famous stage magicians in universe (his father was a stage magician as well).

Comment: It's most likely a combination of coincidence and confirmation bias. I haven't see anything linking the two officially, Butcher began Dresden after someone in a writing class suggested he write a novel similar to the Anita Blake series (at least according to wikipedia and whatever source they used), Dresden is named after Houdini in-story, and HP Book 1 came out in 1997. Storm Front (Dresden Book 1), came out in 2000, but he apparently spent 2-3 years trying to find a publisher. Not impossible, but not a lot of time to read HP and then write the book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### *[A Night at the Magic Castle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0466239/)* (1988)

Determining the earliest example of a wizard named Harry might be next to impossible. There are so many magic-users, and so few common English names, that the earliest example is likely to be quite old  indeed.

That said, one of the earlier examples must be *A Night at the Magic Castle*, where the flying ghost of [Harry Houdini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Houdini), here a literal magician, takes a young boy to Hollywood’s Magic Castle, there to do battle with an evil magician.

This predates the first Harry Potter book by roughly a decade, and *Storm Front* by 12 years.

---

It is worth noting that Harry Houdini is the likely inspiration for most fictional magicians named Harry. As perhaps the most famous illusionist of all time, Houdini’s reputation is guaranteed to be known to most writers. The second example from the question, Harry Dresden, was in fact probably named after Houdini *in-universe*, since his other names come from magicians. Or possibly after [Harry Blackstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Blackstone_Sr.). Blackstone is another possible inspiration for fictional magic-users named Harry, but he is certainly more obscure than Houdini.

Comment: That's a very good answer, especially the part about two possible real-life inspirations. But, as is the tradition, I'll wait some time before marking it as accepted.

Comment: It's explicitly stated in the books that [Harry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Houdini) [Blackstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Blackstone,_Sr.) [Copperfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Copperfield_(illusionist)) Dresden is named after famous stage magicians in universe with Harry coming from Houdini (Harry Dresden's father was a stage magician). I'm not sure if the book is explicit about Blackstone Sr. vs Jr., but that's irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 4):

The 1986 movie [*Troll*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092115/) has *two* characters named Harry Potter and Harry Potter, Jr. respectively. Harry Potter Jr. is the main character and while not a wizard, he does ask the (good) witch lady to teach him to be a wizard.

Comment: Ah, the one movie where everyone has heard about the sequel, but not the original. Kudos for finding something two years earlier than the first answer, even if it's a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

[Harry Houdini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Houdini) was a fictional character created by Erik or Ehrich Weisz.  Since Weisz died in 1926 and was using the name by 1893, he predates the depiction of [his ghost](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/140225/30870) by at least ninety years.

Weisz said that he got the first name from [Harry Kellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Kellar), who was performing as early as 1873.  While Harry was his real name, it is worth noting that every stage magician played a character who could perform real magic while actually using a variety of tricks.  As such, I would argue that they are all fictional in the same way that WWE is fictional.

By that argument, the earliest fictional magician named Harry was Harry Kellar in **1873** (or even 1865, although he wasn't famous then).  Of course, there may have been earlier occurrences of whom we don't know.  But we can trace Harry Dresden to Harry Houdini to Harry Kellar directly.  Houdini at least should also have been known to both the writers of **[Troll](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/140249/30870)** and J. K. Rowling.  And thus we have the explanation of wizards named Harry.  It's all Kellar's fault.

Comment: A stage name is not a fictional protagonist

Comment: @Valorum - Further, I doubt anyone here would accept a WWE answer to this question.